# PHP precedence of operators

Tags: php, boolean, operator-precedence

I read that `=`
has a higher precedence than `and`

Let's say you got

```
$boolone = true;
$booltwo= false;
$res = $boolone and $booltwo;
```

I had guessed this would turn false since `$res = true and false` where true and false equals to false. But since `=` has higher precedence it's supposed to turn true. Which is like this

```
($res = $boolone) and $booltwo;
```

This returns true but my question is why does it return true, shouldn't it return false? Since `$res = $boolone`equals `true`and `$booltwo`is false by default, so we have this: `true and false` which should normally return false, but again, why true?

Simply said:

```
($res = $boolone) and $booltwo;
(true) and false; //returns true?
```

Comment: If this is for actual practical purpose try `$res = $boolone && $booltwo;`

Comment: @mega6382 I just want to understand the theory behind it. Not practical (yet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that

```
$res = $boolone and $booltwo;
```

is equivalent to

```
($res = $boolone) and $booltwo;
```

Because of operator precedence,

```
$res = $boolone
```

is evaluated first, with the value of `$boolone` being assigned to `$res`....

`$booltwo` is then `and`ed with the result of that first evaluation result (`true and false`), but you're doing nothing with that evaluation, so it is simply discarded... it isn't assigned to `$res`, because that assignment has already been completed by the first evaluation.

If you do

```
var_dump($res = $boolone and $booltwo);
```

then you'll see the result of the full evaluation that is discarded, and `$res` is still `true`

Comment: Great answer `+1`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the nice and detailed answer. However, what do you mean by that we're doing nothing with that evaluation?

Comment: `$res = $boolone and $booltwo` is evaluated..... what then happens to the result of that evaluation? Nothing! Unless you do something like the `var_dump()` I've shown in my answer, which displays the result; or `$res2 = ($res = $boolone and $booltwo);`, which assigns the result of the full expression to `$res2` (`$boolone` is still always assigned to `$res`).... then you're not doing anything with the final result of the evaluation

Answer (score 2):

I tested with PHP 5.6.30 but I did not get results that suggest `=` binds tighter than `&&`.

```
<?php
$boolone = true;
$booltwo = false;

var_dump($res = ($boolone && $booltwo));
var_dump($res);

var_dump($res = $boolone && $booltwo);
var_dump($res);

var_dump(($res = $boolone) && $booltwo);
var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
bool(false) // $res = ($boolone && $booltwo) ... $res = (true && false)
bool(false) // $res after assignment is false

bool(false) // $res = $boolone && $booltwo ... $res = true && false
bool(false) // $res after assignment is false

bool(false) // ($res = $boolone) && $booltwo ... ($res = true) && false
bool(true)  // $res after assignment is true
```

Conclusions:

Assignment *does NOT* bind tighter than `&&` by default. You have to use parens to override it.

Update: As @Piyin points out in the comment, `&&` is not the same as `and` in PHP. The page https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php shows that they fall in two different places in the operator precedence hierarchy.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php states:

> The reason for the two different variations of "and" and "or" operators is that they operate at different precedences. (See Operator Precedence.)

Comment: You're right and wrong. You're testing with `&&` instead of `and`. Relevant information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php Both tests joined: https://3v4l.org/iLrsH

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong here:

> This returns true but my question is why does it return true,
>   shouldn't it return false?

Well, it doesn't return true. It returns false. Probably you've mistaken result of `(true) and false` with content of `$res` which is equal to `($res = $boolone)`. You did not assign result of `(true) and false` to `$res`.